# Why “accounts/login/?next=/” is coming in url of Django on local development server ? | Way to remove “accounts/login/?next=/” from the url

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

Why “accounts/login/?next=/” is coming in url of Django on local development server ? | Way to remove “accounts/login/?next=/” from the url .

I have used class based views and used LoginRequiredMixin.
Can anyone tell me why the path changes from **/login** to **accounts/login/?next=/**

```
path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

Comment: It indicates that the page after you login will match the '/' url path. it's usually what happens when you try to access a protected view without being logged in.

Answer (score 1):

just add this to your settings.py

`LOGIN_URL = 'login'`

From Django Docs:

> The URL or named URL pattern where requests are redirected for login when using the login_required() decorator...

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#login-url

Comment: Add some information on where to find the settings.py file. For someone that doesn't know its not clear enough

Comment: Settings.py location is one of Django basics, so I wouldn't worry that a Django dev (be it beginner or learning) would consider this an issue. That being said, this answer should be expanded, to explain the solution provided.

Answer (score 0):

because you have used this in urls.py

```
path('login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login')
```

just remove this url it will be fixed

use this for admin login

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```